# Google Maps Marker Filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the following jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/inkedraskal/zeLon7cs/2/

You'll notice when the map loads all the points are showing, and filtering on its own seems to work correctly.  **However**, when you click a filter, (project for example), it will show only projects, but if you click it again, it wont reset the markers.  As well as, if you say click **News** and then **Stuff**, then click **Stuff** again, it wont show the markers only applying to **news** again (still shows markers that apply to both **News** and **Stuff**, instead of just **News**).

Any tips would greatly be appreciated.

I have create a **list-items** to **filter** the markers on **click**

```
<div class="filters">
  <ul>
      <li>
          <a href="#" data-filterby="type" data-filtervalue="project">Projects</a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#" data-filterby="type" data-filtervalue="news">News</a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#" data-filterby="type" data-filtervalue="stuff">stuff</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
      <li>
          <a href="#" data-filterby="date" data-filtervalue="201401">Jan</a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#" data-filterby="date" data-filtervalue="201402">Feb</a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#" data-filterby="date" data-filtervalue="201403">Mar</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

at the bottom my JS you'll see the following:

```
$(document).on('click', '.filters a', function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var $target = $(event.target);
     var type = $target.data('filterby');
     var value = $target.data('filtervalue');
     $(this).toggleClass('active');
     $.each(map.markers, function () {
         if (this.filter[type] && this.filter[type].indexOf(value.toString()) >= 0) {
             if (this.map == null) {
                  this.setMap(map);
             }
         } else {
             this.setMap(null);
         }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop to hide/show each marker, for each individual marker you are only checking if that marker has the clicked on filter value. You need to check each marker against every active filter.

```
 $(document).on('click', '.filters a', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $(this).toggleClass('active');

  // create an array of active filters
  var activeFilters = [];
  $(".filters a.active").each(function() {
    activeFilters.push({
      by: $(this).data("filterby"),
      value: $(this).data("filtervalue").toString()
    });
  });

  if (activeFilters.length === 0) { // if there are no active filters, show all markers
    for (var i = 0; i < map.markers.length; i++) {
      map.markers[i].setMap(map);
    }
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < map.markers.length; i++) { // for each marker
      var marker = map.markers[i]; // just to make the next code easier

      var missingActiveFilter = false;
      // check if marker has every active filter
      for (var j = 0; j < activeFilters.length; j++) {
        var filter = activeFilters[j];
        if (filter.by === "type" && marker.filter.type.indexOf(filter.value) === -1 || filter.by === "date" && marker.filter.date.indexOf(filter.value) === -1) {
          missingActiveFilter = true;
          break;
        }
      }

      if (missingActiveFilter) {
        marker.setMap(null);
      } else {
        marker.setMap(map);
      }

    }
  }
});
```

});

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zeLon7cs/8/)

Comment: this is awesome, and thank you for leaving notes!  I really appreciate it.  Can you add back date filter by chance?

Comment: @RMH My bad. Working on it now.

Comment: @RMH Updated the answer and the fiddle.

Comment: awesome. Thank you. When you are checking if the marker has every active filter, in the if statement just below, what is "beak;" doing?

Comment: @RMH `break` terminates the current loop. At that point, we definitely know that the marker doesn't meet all the filters so we can stop the loop without checking the other filters. We don't strictly need to exit the loop there, it just saves some time/computations. 

P.S. I don't get alerted when you edit a comment. It was pure luck that I saw you asked this question.

Comment: @Foxsk8 Sorry, looks like OP's JSFiddle account has been deleted. I don't have a copy of the code.